# If not catched then react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my code,

```js
msg.author.send(helpembed)
  .catch(() =>{
    send(msg,":no_entry_sign: **Your DMs are closed! Open them so I can help you out!** :no_entry_sign:");
});
msg.react("✅");
```

and I was wondering if I could somehow do a code to say: If no catch (no errors) react with ✅. How could I do that?

Comment: how about a `try...catch` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [what the `.then(…, …)` method does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
msg.author.send(helpembed).then(() => {
  msg.react("✅");
}, err => {
  send(msg,":no_entry_sign: **Your DMs are closed! Open them so I can help you out!** :no_entry_sign:");
});
```